# How to run php file in android?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have a php file on the web server and I want to run it.

I used `HttpURLConnection`, but the program dies.

I think there is a mistake in the `HttpURLConnection` section.

Here is my code,

I may not have completely finished writing the `HttpURLConnection` section.

Please help me.

```
if(v == buttonSendPush) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://server adress/push_notification.php"); 
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000); 
        conn.setDoInput(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(conn!=null){
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are not using webview ??

Comment: you are running the code on the **server** not android

Comment: @Rahul 
I am implementing PUSH function now. Click the button on the android to run the ' push _ notification.php ' file. (push_notification.php : A file that sends a ' push message ' to all ' token ' stored in the DB. So I want to connect the ' push_notification.php ' file, not to see the php file on the screen.

Comment: Then create a REST api and from that you can call your .php file.

Comment: Remove setDoOutput()

Comment: If the program dies you can find the reason in the logcat. Search amd then post some relevant lines.

Comment: You need to get the `InputStream` from the `conn` in that way you can listen to server response.